# jwPlayer sendEvent not initiating in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, jwplayer

I have a couple videos embedded in HTML and in JS, I am using jQuery tools method **OnBeforeSeek: function(event, index)** to find the current video and set an interval to do a sendEvent to play the video once found. The code below is working in all browsers **BUT IE**.

```
if (currentIsVideo.length > 0) {
              playLoop = setInterval(function () { currentIsVideo.each(function () { try { this.sendEvent('PLAY'); clearInterval(playLoop); } catch (e) { } }); }, 200);
```

Is there a work around for this?

**EDIT:** This code is breaking in FireFox aswell. I am using scrollable to scroll through assets, and the first 2 assets are videos embedded in HTML using jwPlayer. In Firefox, i believe this is breaking the scrollable after the first video.

**EDIT2:** NO LONGER BREAKING IN FIREFOX. Used sendEvent('PLAY', '**true**')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to update to the latest version of jwPlayer for it to work in IE. I am unable to edit any JS objects with my current version.